# The output is entirely different in chrome - windows and safari - mac

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
if(sel.getRangeAt) {
  if(sel.rangecount){
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    range.insertNode("<span id="xXmergefield" class="tag mergefield" data-replacement="{MERGEFIELD FirstName}" contenteditable="false" style="background-color: rgba(93, 0, 255, 0.75);">First Name<i id="xXmergefield firstnameXx13-remover" class="fas fa-times remover"></i></span>")
   var range2 = range.cloneRange();
console.log("test",range2)
  }
}
```

In console we are getting different data in windows-chrome and mac - safari
cloneRange have the list of attributes such as innerText, innerHTML, outerText.....etc
I think cloneRange is not supported as much in safari.....is there any method instead of cloneRange for safari in mac.

In windows chrome : Working as expected.....

```
innerHTML: "Did You know??? <span id="xXmergefield" class="tag mergefield" data-replacement="{MERGEFIELD FirstName}" contenteditable="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255,
0.75);">FirstName<i id="xXmergefield firstnameXx1-remover" class="fas fa-times remover"></i></span> "

outerHTML: "<div id="mycontent-header" contenteditable="true" class="mycontent" style="user-select: text;">Did You know??? <span id="xXmergefield" class="tag mergefield" data-replacement="{MERGEFIELD FirstName}" contenteditable="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);">FirstName<i id="xXmergefield firstnameXx1-remover" class="fas fa-times remover"></i></span> </div>"
```

In safari - mac   Not working

```
innerHTML: “<div class=\“row\“><div class=\“cell label\“>Description</div><div class=\“cell\“><input></div> <div class=\“cell label pad\“>Active</div><di…”
innerText: “Description↵↵Active↵Action type↵↵Trigger↵↵Days↵↵Run at time↵10:30↵Disable template↵Disable unsubscribe↵Email fields:↵Subject↵Appoin

outerHTML: “<div class=\“content\“><div class=\“row\“><div class=\“cell label\“>Description</div><div class=\“cell\“><input></div> <div class=\“cell labe…”
outerText: “Description↵↵Active↵Action type↵↵Trigger↵↵Days↵↵Run at time↵10:30↵Disable template↵Disable unsubscribe↵Email fields:↵Subject↵Appointment
```

These description, Active,Actions......etc these are the labels in the current page..which are at the top of the page.

Comment: In chrome, where we select and rightclick to add the fields its takes the very nearby text and add the corresponding span tag into it. But in safari, while we select and right click...its takes the text from the top of the page....so its not adding the corresponding span tag

Comment: Your formatting makes your question unreadable. Indent code with the button

Comment: ok....while executing the above code in chrome and safari...the datas are different..means...
In chrome,
innerHTML: "Did You know??? <span id="xXmergefield " class="tag mergefield " data-replacement="{MERGEFIELD FirstName}" contenteditable="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);">FirstName<i id="xXmergefield firstnameXx1-remover" class="fas fa-times remover"></i></span> "

Comment: In safari - mac,
innerHTML: “<div class=\“row\“><div class=\“cell label\“>Description</div><div class=\“cell\“><input></div> <div class=\“cell label pad\“>Active</div><di…”

These Description, Active are the lables in the top of the page....